# MSVC equivalent to __builtin_popcount?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, built-in

What is the equivalent to [`__builtin_popcount`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) as found in GCC and Clang, for MSVC-10?

Comment: Have a look at [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231(v=vs.90).aspx) intrinsics (or the [SSE4 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531475%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)), else you can always use something from [here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Population+Count)

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the comments provided:

- [`__popcnt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231(v=vs.100).aspx) available through `<intrin.h>`
- [`_mm_popcnt_u64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531475(v=vs.100).aspx) with SSE4 and `<nmmintrin.h>`

Comment: Be careful with this; it will not work with ARM CPUs, or x86 CPUs which don't support the ABM instruction set.

Answer (score 27):

With this code snippet you get the GCC builtin when building with MSVC :

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  include <intrin.h>
#  define __builtin_popcount __popcnt
#endif
```

(Works from Visual Studio 2008).

Comment: It's `_MSC_VER` not `__MSC_VER`

Comment: It's not really the equivalent. The function in GCC [will just use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387998/count-bits-1-on-an-integer-as-fast-as-gcc-builtin-popcountint#comment90027394_51387998) its plain x86 assembly, unless being told otherwise with a specific march/instruction set. `__popcnt` in MSVC [is instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/popcnt16-popcnt-popcnt64) the literal hardware instruction *popcnt*.

Answer (score 8):

The `__popcnt` intrinsic mentioned above doesn't work on ARM, or even all x86 CPUs (it requires [ABM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Bit_Manipulation) instruction set).  You shouldn't use it directly; instead, if you're on x86/amd64 you should use the `__cpuid` intrinsic to determine at runtime if the processor supports `popcnt`.

Keep in mind that you probably don't want to issue a `cpuid` for every `popcnt` call; you'll want to store the result somewhere.  If your code is always going to be single-threaded this is trivial, but if you have to be thread-safe you'll have to use something like a [One-Time Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363808(v=vs.85).aspx).  That will only work with Windows ≥ Vista, though; if you need to work with older versions you'll need to roll your own (or use something from a third-party).

For machines without ABM (or if runtime detection isn't worth it), there are several portable versions at [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) (look for "Counting bits set").  My favorite version works for any type `T` up to 128-bits:

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & (T)~(T)0/3);                           // temp
v = (v & (T)~(T)0/15*3) + ((v >> 2) & (T)~(T)0/15*3);      // temp
v = (v + (v >> 4)) & (T)~(T)0/255*15;                      // temp
c = (T)(v * ((T)~(T)0/255)) >> (sizeof(T) - 1) * CHAR_BIT; // count
```

If you want a drop-in version you can use [the builtin module in portable-snippets](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/tree/master/builtin) (full disclosure: portable-snippets is one of my projects), which should work pretty much anywhere.

Comment: No need to get fancy with CPU detection.  Do it before starting any threads, e.g. with a `static const cpuid_result = cpuid();` so it runs at program startup.

Comment: Interesting generic version of the popcount bithack.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/224132 for the canonical Q&A).